# No muestra datos data en javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Resulta que estoy extrayendo estos datos de mi base:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando los trato de poner en los campos que le corresponde, me dice que están indefinidos, el código  que estoy usando para asignarlos es el siguiente:

```js
$('#profesor').change(function(){
   $.get("./actions/buscar_profesor.php", {codigo_profesor:     $('#profesor').val()}, function(data){
    $('#nombres').val(data.nombre);
    $('#apellido').val(data.apellido);
    $('#tel').val(data.telefono);
    $('#mail').val(data.correo);
    $('#pwd').val(data.password);
    $("#curso1 option[value='"+ data.codigo_nivel +"']").attr("selected", true);
   });
});
```

En esta imagen pueden observar lo que les comentaba sobre que el data me aparece indefinido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que estoy haciendo mal, ya que como pueden ver el data trae la información que solicite por el script de php, pero cuando hago referencia en javascript a cada campo del data me dice que no esta definido es como si no existiera ese campo.

Por cierto el script de php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
  require_once 'conexion.php';
  $codigo_profesor = $_GET['codigo_profesor'];

  $sql = "SELECT profesores.codigo_profesor, nombre, apellido, telefono, correo, password, 
         codigo_nivel FROM profesores, usuariosprof WHERE profesores.codigo_profesor = 
         $codigo_profesor AND usuariosprof.codigo_profesor = $codigo_profesor";

 $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

 echo json_encode(array("codigo_nivel"=>$row['codigo_nivel'], 
                       "codigo_profesor"=>$row['codigo_profesor'], "nombre"=>$row['nombre'], 
                       "apellido"=>$row['apellido'], "telefono"=>$row['telefono'], 
                       "correo"=>$row['correo'], "password"=>$row['password']));
```

?>

---

Esto es lo que me muestra console.log(data):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando pongo console.log(data[0]), se supone que deberia tomar lo que tiene codigo nivel osea que deberia mostrar el valor de 1, pero lo que muestra es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que pueda ser. y lo recorro haciendo referencia directa a cada campo.

JSON.parse(data)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que información te regresa en data, puedes hacer un console log

Comment: Parece que data es un array

Comment: Entonces tienes que recorrer tu array para acceder a el ítem,  ó si solo te interesa el primer arreglo, entonces accede a data[0], para obtener cada propiedad

Comment: Hola @EduardoJaramilloLicea hago referencia tal como me dices, pero coge carácter por carácter, en mi pregunta muestro en la primera imagen la información que trae data y al final esta el script de php que uso para obtener esa información

Comment: El script mas alla de que generas un array() y lo codificas, no hay problema, mas bien puedes agregar el console.log de data, y como es que lo recorres que según comentas te toma por carácter

Comment: Hola @EduardoJaramilloLicea, puse la info que me pediste, gracias

Comment: Creo que te esta tomando todo como una cadena, si aplicas un JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Hola @EduardoJaramilloLicea esto es lo que muestra JSON.parse(data)

Comment: puede especificarle que la informacion que recibe es de tipo json.

Comment: cómo @tecnobyte

Comment: Puedes especificar el DataType, que es el formato que esperas como comenta @tecnobyte, [jQuery get() Method] https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp, a Json, o puedes usar el dato pareado y desde ahí obtener la información

Comment: ok gracias ahora pruebo y les comento como me fue

Comment: Hola @tecnobyte, Eduardo Jaramillo LIcea
Seguí la recomendación que me dieron, le especifique a mi función que recibiría un objeto tipo json, pero cuando accedo al nombre por data.nombre, me dice que no esta definido, pero al mirar que tiene data observo que tiene la información que le solicite en el script de php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar mandando el parametro  get explicitamente en la url del servidor de la siguiente manera.

```
$('#profesor').change(function(){
   let codigo_profesor = $('#profesor').val(); // obtienes la variable
   // aquí le mandas por get el parametro codigo_profesor concatenando el valor de la variable
   $.get(`./actions/buscar_profesor.php?codigo_profesor=${codigo_profesor}`, function(data){
    $('#nombres').val(data.nombre);
    $('#apellido').val(data.apellido);
    $('#tel').val(data.telefono);
    $('#mail').val(data.correo);
    $('#pwd').val(data.password);
    $("#curso1 option[value='"+ data.codigo_nivel +"']").attr("selected", true);
   });
},"json");
```

Mi teoría es que esta confundiendo lo que debería ser los params y cuando pasa al recibir la información no lo almacena en el callback de la respuesta

Comment: Hola, cuando lo hago de esa manera no pasa el dato al script de php y me genera un error en la consulta de mysql, pero cuando le hago un alert a codigo_profesor si me muestra que almaceno el código

Comment: la solución fue como me habían dicho informarle a la función que recibiría un objeto tipo json, el error lo tenia por que antes de cerrar la función tenia que ponerle "json", una vez hecho trae la info sin problemas